# Can't call C# function from other .cs file

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf, xaml, oop

I am really stuck on calling my function `InlogLeerling()` from .cs file `Login.cs` into `MainPage.xaml.cs`.

I did try everything and I already found some answers but I do not understand how I can get it working in my project. When i call the function `InlogLeerling()` I get the error `There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'mainpage' of 'Login.InlogLeerling(MainPage)'`

Here is the code I am using in my `Login.cs`

```
namespace VerlofXamarin.Logical_Layer
{
    public class Login
    {
        public string pu_Gebruikersnaam, pu_Wachtwoord, pu_LogLeerling;

        string Gebruikersnaam
        {
            get { return pu_Gebruikersnaam; }
            set { pu_Gebruikersnaam = value; }
        }

        string Wachtwoord
        {
            get { return pu_Wachtwoord; }
            set { pu_Wachtwoord = value; }
        }

        public MainPage mainpage;

        private void InlogLeerling(MainPage mainpage)
        {
            Data_Layer.Verbinding vv = new Data_Layer.Verbinding();

            this.mainpage = mainpage;
            try
            {
                if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(pu_Gebruikersnaam) == true || string.IsNullOrEmpty(pu_Wachtwoord) == true)
                {
                    mainpage.pu_LeerlingLog = "Vul gebruikersnaam en wachtwoord in!";
                    return;
                }

                vv.con.Open();
                MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand cmd = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand("SELECT leerlinggebruikersnaam, leerlingwachtwoord FROM arabignl_project.myfirstmodule$leerlinglogin WHERE (leerlinggebruikersnaam = @gebruiker AND leerlingwachtwoord = @wachtwoord)", vv.con);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gebruiker", pu_Gebruikersnaam.ToString());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@wachtwoord", pu_Wachtwoord.ToString());

                MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                if (reader.HasRows)
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        mainpage.pu_LeerlingLog = "Inloggen gelukt";
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    mainpage.pu_LeerlingLog = "Inloggen mislukt";
                }
                reader.Close();
            }
            catch (MySqlException ex)
            {
                mainpage.pu_LeerlingLog = ex.ToString();
            }
            finally
            {
                vv.con.Close();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

And the `MainPage.xaml.cs`

```
namespace VerlofXamarin
{
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public Login login;

        public string pu_LeerlingLog
        {
            get { return LoginLog.Text; }
            set { LoginLog.Text = value; }
        }

        public string pu_LeerlingGebruikersnaam
        {
            get { return LeerlingGebruikersnaam.Text; }
        }

        public string pu_LeerlingWachtwoord
        {
            get { return LeerlingWachtwoord.Text; }
        }

        public void LoginKlik(Login login)
        {
            this.login = login;
            login.InlogLeerling();
        }
```

I have already tried so many things.

Answer (score 2):

You have two problems in your code.

1. You can´t call any private member from outside your class. So make your method public
2. your method expects a parameter of type `MainPage`. So you have to *provide* it, which is exactly what your error states:

   ```
   public void LoginKlik(Login login)
   {
       this.login = login;
       login.InlogLeerling(this);
   }
   ```

Apart from those you shouldn´t expose a field publicily. Instead use a public property which you can *modify within your class* and *read outside your class* `Login`:

```
public MainPage MainPage { get; private set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should study access modifier. With private, other classes could not access it. So you could change it to either internal or public. Here is reference
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/access-modifiers

```
    internal void InlogLeerling(MainPage mainpage)
```

Answer (score 0):

You will not be able to call the method because they are not in same class.
When you give an access modifier of **privte**, the accesses is possible only within the class.
If you would like to give more access there is:

**protected** - A protected member is accessible within its class and by derived class instances.

**Internal**- Internal types or members are accessible only within files in the same assembly.(i.e. the same compiled program)

**public**- . Public access is the most permissive access level. There are no restrictions

Therefor by using internal or public (depends on what you need in more large aspect) you will be able to access this method within other classes in your project